# Comment a statement in shell script file using sed command at run time?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to comment a if statement in a shell script file using sed command.

Code snippet:

```
if[$z='LZ'||$x='LW']
then
        echo "This my test for sed and I am successful"
else
        echo "This my test for sed and my try failed"
fi
```

I used

```
**sed -i -e 's\if\#if\g' test.sh**
```

it works but if I give below command:

```
**sed -i -e "s\if[$z='LZ'||$x='LW']\#if[$z='LZ'||$x='LW']\g" test.sh**
```

it doesn't work

Let me know if you need some more data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to do... if you commented out if, what matches else and fi? it doesn't make sense. you'd better state what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr currently I am trying to just comment this single line and add another line as if false

Comment: no it's not what you want to do... if you want to have the if branch for testing or whatever reason, you should control it via variables, and set that variable to false by default. something like $DEBUG_OPT$. if you have lots of this, you should consider using functions.

Comment: Consider running your shell script through [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net/) before you post it in a question here. While your question is about how to use sed to match a variety of questions, the fact that your source text is an unrunnable broken script may be distracting.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to match the if statement (which is missing some spaces, fix that), just replace the difficult characters by dots.

```
sed -i -e 's/if.$z=.LZ.||$x=.LW.]/#&/' test.sh
```